# Is there a update manager whitout gnome dependencies for xfce?

Tags: apt, cron, xfce

I'm looking a update manager for Debian Xfce. I installed xfce on a computer which will be use by laypersons. Therefore, I want another way (graphical) to launch `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. But I don't want to slow the system by adding gnome dependencies (update-manager-gnome is then not a solution).

The solution using `cron` configured to launch commands such as `'apt-get update; apt-get upgrade -y --force-yes; apt-get dist-upgrade -y --force-yes;'` seems to me too dangerous. I would like to offer a choice by graphical way.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but [`unattended-upgrades`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/unattended-upgrades) can install updates in a quite safe way.

Comment: What about `synaptic`? -- I believe it is still available and usable http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software) -- although no longer maintained.  BTW: *"I don't want to slow the system by adding gnome dependencies"* -- it won't.  They just take up a few MB on disk, and the package manager loads little pieces of them.  If that's what you'd prefer, just use it -- it won't matter WRT performance at all.

Comment: Does `synaptic` offers background update check? It seems to me you have to start `synatic` and then upgrade the system. I'm looking for a software which update on the background and, then, offer to upgrade to the user.

Comment: `unattended-upgrades` solves partially my problem (for security upgrades). Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as jofel commented there is unattended-upgrade to automate the upgrade process, there is also the `update-manager-core` package that gives you access to the `update-manager-text` binary. Also, the normal package manager will do this quite nicely whenever you ask them (`apt-get upgrade` or `aptitude full-upgrade`).

[This post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=68698#p389702) also suggest that there's no update manager GUI for XFCE (I don't use it myself) so you either will be working with `unattended-upgrades` or pull `update-manager-gnome` which as far I see [doesn't have any gnome dependency.](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/update-manager-gnome)